# How to read / readSream a directory containing files with completely different schemas

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

What if I have this:

```
Data:
/user/1_data/1.parquet
/user/1_data/2.parquet
/user/1_data/3.parquet

/user/2_data/1.parquet
/user/2_data/2.parquet

/user/3_data/1.parquet
/user/3_data/2.parquet
```

Each directory has files containing completely different schemas.

I don't want to have to create a single stream job for each folder. At the same time, I also want to save them in different locations.

How would I read / readStream them all without having collect data to the driver or hard coding the directories path?

Comment: would you be open to creating separate streaming queries for different directories inside a single spark job?

Comment: If they are dynamically created, sure. I don't want to hard code 1 stream for each folder